# Parsing Text with Python RegEx re.findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a long string that I need to parse in groups, but need to control it more.

```
import re

RAW_Data = "Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 3456 Numbers and this stuff2* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 78910 Numbers and this stuff3* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff4* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff5* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff6* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff7* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A52 & A53)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff8* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff9* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff10* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff11* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff12* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff13* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff14* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff15* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff16*"

fromnode = re.findall('(.*?)(?=\*\s)', RAW_Data)

print fromnode

del fromnode
del RAW_Data
```

The results are: 'Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff', '', ' ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 3456 Numbers and this stuff2' *........ and so on.*

I can't seem to capture only the strings like "Name Multiple Words Testing With 3456 Numbers and this stuff" and omit all of the strings like "((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41))".  Any  help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will the `Bla...` stuff always be in parentheses and the wording of the `Name Mul...` always be identical?

Comment: Do you just want the stuff outside parenthesis?

Comment: Yes the Bla Bla Bla stuff will always be structured within the double parentheses.  There's also a group of single parentheses in there.  I use another     re.findall(('\(\((.*?)\)\)', RAW_Data) to capture those sections.  For now I want to ignore them.  Name Mul.... will not always be the same though.  I dumped some text in there to have multiple words, spaces and numbers as sort of a catch all.

Comment: @Laurel yes, I pretty much only want the stuff outside of the parenthesis.  Something like all of the groups of "Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff", Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff2", etc...

Comment: And you can't just replace everything in parenthesis why?

Comment: I tried replacing everything within parenthesis with just a "" but it didn't return the matches as separate strings.  It was just one long string without the sections I didn't want.  This is all running in a loop that updates multiple fields within table with the parsed text

Comment: @user1457123: Isn't my answer working for you? You need *matches as separate strings* - `re.split` provides you a list of those substrings you are seeking.

Comment: Wiktor, I haven't had a chance to test it yet.  I'll try first thing in the morning when I get back into the office.  Thanks to everyone so far for the help.

Comment: It worked like a champ Wiktor.  I ended up using the first suggestion as a re.split.  Thanks again to everyone for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split with

```
r'\*\s*\({2}.*?\){2}\s*'
```

The pattern ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH8eJ0/1)) matches:

- `\*` - a literal asterisk
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\({2}` - exactly 2 opening parentheses
- `.*?` - zero or more characters other than a newline (NOTE: add the `re.S` flag if you need to match across several lines) as few as possible up to the first
- `\){2}` - double closing parentheses
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace.

ALSO: The [same, but unrolled (thus, a bit more efficient) regex](https://regex101.com/r/yH8eJ0/2):

```
\*\s*\({2}[^)]*(?:\)(?!\))[^)]*)*\){2}\s*
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/XjrxIw):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\*\s*\({2}.*?\){2}\s*')
test_str = "Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 3456 Numbers and this stuff2* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 78910 Numbers and this stuff3* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff4* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff5* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff6* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff7* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A52 & A53)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff8* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff9* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff10* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff11* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff12* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff13* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff14* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff15* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69)) Name Multiple Words Testing With 1234 Numbers and this stuff16*"
print(re.split(p, test_str))
```

**UPDATE**

A regex for use with `re.findall`:

```
(?:\*\s*\(\([^)]*(?:\)(?!\))[^)]*)*\)\))?\s*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\s*\(\()[^*]*)*)\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bG6tM6/1)

Horrified at the looks of it? It is just the unrolled version of a much simpler [`(?:\*\s*\(\(.*?\)\))?\s*(.*?(?=\*\s*(?:\(\(|$)))`](https://regex101.com/r/oX9fF9/1).

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WoiFJn).

Comment: I added the pattern for use with `re.findall`. Now, I guess the question is answered.

Comment: Again, thanks Wiktor.  I went ahead and ran the re.findall suggestion.  It works as well.  The only thing I noticed was that it captured a single whitespace at the end.

Comment: Please share the input string, and I will see to it.

Comment: I used the same input string as originally posted.  No worries though.  The re.split solution gives me what I need.  Thanks

Comment: There is an empty space, right? Try [`(?!$)(?:\*\s*\(\([^)]*(?:\)(?!\))[^)]*)*\)\))?\s*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\s*\(\()[^*]*)*)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/yZ4jW3/1).

Comment: Well as expected the real data that I am parsing wasn't entered in a very clean way.  So now I have to figure out how to get around a missing "*".  Sometimes it's there and sometimes it's not.  I thought about modify the source data to include the "*" anywhere that is doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to only dwell on parentheses as a delimiter try using `(?s)(?:\*?\s*\(\(.*?\)\))?\s*(.*?(?=\*?\s*(?:\(\(|$)))`

Comment: Update - by adding a second "*" after "'\*....." that allowed it to capture whether the * existed or not.  I'm a newb and can't figure out how to properly copy/paste cose into comments.

Comment: To paste code into comments, use `\``code`\``: `code`. However, doesn't [`(?!$)(?:\*?\s*\(\([^)]*(?:\)(?!\))[^)]*)*\)\))?\s*([^(]*(?:\((?!\()[^(]*)*)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/yZ4jW3/2) work?